# Can a wife receive a blood transfusion from her husband?

Tags: quran, hadith, husband-wife, reference-request, blood

My cousin's wife gave birth to a child and at that time she needs blood urgently, her husband (my cousin) gave blood to her. But later on some of people said them, that it is not permissible in islam (they didn't gave any hadith regarding this matter).

I just want to know can a husband give blood to his wife?
Is it permissible in Islam if yes then please elaborate with Quran or Hadith?

Comment: It would be great of you could quote an argument they used. Many people say X is haram or X is halal without knowledge and that is a sinful behaviour.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i also prefer it but i wasn't present there and i don't know what exactly was the argument they used. i was just told by another person now i'm curious about it.

Answer (score 2):

In the Qur'an Allah () says:

> **He has only forbidden to you** dead animals, **blood,** the flesh of swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah . **But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful**. ([2:173](https://legacy.quran.com/2/173))

Al-Qurtobi in his tafsir says that blood here is meant in general, so it is basically forbidden to use it or consummate it unless a necessity occurs see also [6:119](https://legacy.quran.com/6/119). (For details refer to the tafsir 14th case الرابعة عشرة [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=2&ayano=173) in Arabic). Al-Qurtobi later also discussed the matter of necessity and quoted different cases.

Note that this verse doesn't say that blood has any influence on the marital status of a husband and wife. And that in case of necessity this prohibition might be lifted. So if there's no other person around who has the same blood type or could help it is clearly allowed for the husband to give his blood to his wife and vice versa. (see also fatwa 419 in Arabic [here](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%AB%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A1%20(%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AE%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D9%86%D9%82%D8%AD%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D9%81%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A9)/%D8%A5%D8%B9%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A3%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%AF%D9%85%20%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7:/i766&d1101596&c&p1), you may find a similar answer in Arabic or Urdu in islamqa #[133135](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/133135/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%85-%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7))

From my understanding of an urgent intervention I'd say that this case was a necessity and therefore there's no harm in using this blood. Note that many scholars say a Muslim -in such cases- can both give and receive blood even from non-Muslims (see fore example other fatwas on the link from al-eman.com).